# How to prevent a special character from deletion in EditText in Android?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, character

How can I prevent certain character from deletion in EditText?

for example, prevent "," character from deletion by Cursor in below text:

`"Amir,Mahdy"`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to check the character in a TextWatcher as below :

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Get cursor position
        int cursorPosition = editText.getSelectionStart();

        // Check if the previous character is "," and move your cursor
        if (s.charAt(cursorPosition - 1) == ',')
            editText.setSelection(cursorPosition - 2);
         }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    } 

});
```

Comment: hi thanks for answer @Guillaume LEFEVRE i check and tell you what's going on!

Comment: Only problem with this is that if the user is typing and presses "," then they may keep skipping backwards. This could be overcome however by listening for a KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK and including a Boolean switch to check whether or not the user is deleting.

Comment: It didn't work! "," keeps deleting!! and in some condition before minus getselectionstart become -1!

Comment: @AmirHosseinGhasemi Did you try moving it to OnTextChanged to see whether that made a difference? I've used code similar to this before for a similar purpose and it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

Global variables:

```
private String   lastText     = "";
private int      countOfCommas= 0;
private EditText editText;
```

Code:

```
editText = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText));
updateText("Amir,Mahdy");

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int new_countOfCommas = s.toString().length() - s.toString().replace(",", "").length();
        if(new_countOfCommas < countOfCommas) {
            int cursor_pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
            editText.setText(lastText);
            if(cursor_pos <= lastText.length()) {
                editText.setSelection(cursor_pos);
            }
        } else {
            countOfCommas = s.toString().length() - s.toString().replace(",", "").length();
            lastText = s.toString();
        }
    }
});
```

Function to set text programmatically:

```
void updateText(String str) {
    countOfCommas = str.length() - str.replace(",", "").length();
    lastText = str;
    editText.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: hi @ByteHamster, thank you for your answer :)  there is two bug in this code, the first is I cannot add "," myself anymore, and the second one is, it doesn't seem work on batch text input, for example: "Amir," as a text copied or added programmatically! in fact I want to use it in chips view (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) and cannot add suggested string to my edittext, what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've faced the same problem, prevent user from deleting special character, in my case decimal character. Here is how I did it.
in `strings.xml` add this:

`<item type="id" name="SEPARATOR" />`

than on `EditText` `addTextChangedListener` and in method `beforeTextChanged` add this:

```
int position = editText.getText().toString().indexOf(your_special_character);
editTrxt.setTag(R.id.SEPARATOR, position);
```

than in `afterTextChanged` just return back that character like this:

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
try {
  if (!text.contains(your_special_character +"")){
     int position = (int)editText.getTag(R.id.SEPARATOR);
     text = new StringBuilder(text).insert(position, separator).toString();
  }
}catch (Exception ignored){
}
```